How to get token for Google Text-to-Speech with gargle in R without using a JSON file of a service account?
Goal
Use google text to speech REST API in a shiny app. It requires a token as shown below.
Obtaining token and making an API request
I downloaded a service account key (JSON) file, put it in my working directory and then ran the following to obtain token:
  # Get a token
  token <- gargle::credentials_service_account(
    path = Sys.getenv("GL_AUTH"),
    scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  )

where, GL_AUTH is an environment variable that contains the path to the JSON file. Then I can use it as token$credentials$access_token:
request_body <- "Code"

httr2::request("https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize") |>
    httr2::req_method("POST") |>
    httr2::req_headers(
      Authorization = paste0("Bearer ", token$credentials$access_token),
      `Content-Type` = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      `x-goog-user-project` = Sys.getenv("PROJECT_ID"),
    ) |>
    httr2::req_body_json(request_body) |>
    httr2::req_perform()

Question
I put all my app code in a github repo which is then used by Google Cloud Run for deployment. But I don't think it is a good idea to push the JSON file to the repo. How do I obtain the token without using the JSON file for my deployed app?
